# Get numeric value only from form that has ids as array with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms

I was searching for solution, but did not find any

I have this code:

```
<form name="frm_hs100">
    <input id="hs100[1]" name="hs100[1]" type="checkbox">
    <input id="hs100[2]" name="hs100[2]" type="checkbox">
</form>

$('[name^=hs100]').click(function() {
    if ($(event.target).is(":checked")){
        //true
    }
    else {
        //false
      }
    console.log(event.target.id);
    });
```

console.log prints "hs100[1]", but how do I get only #1 or #2 based on clicked checkbox?

Comment: Use string.replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use classes and data-attributes

```js
$('.my_box').on('click', function() {
    if ( this.checked ){
        //true
    } else {
        //false
    }
    console.log( $(this).data('value') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="frm_hs100">
    <input id="hs100[1]" class="my_box" data-value="1" name="hs100[1]" type="checkbox">
    <input id="hs100[2]" class="my_box" data-value="2" name="hs100[2]" type="checkbox">
</form>
```

Comment: Great, looks data-value is best option for me. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the ids will always start with 'hs100[' and end with ']' then you can simply strip away those letters and replace them with blank space.

```
$('[name^=hs100]').click(function() {
if ($(event.target).is(":checked")){
    //true
}
else {
    //false
  }
var $consolePrint = event.target.id.replace('hs100[','').replace(']','');
console.log($consolePrint);
});
```

I made the printed number into a variable to make it easier to read through.

I also noticed that the console log was outputting the numbers whether I was checking or unchecking the checkboxes, that's what you want it to do?

Comment: Thanks, this is also good solution. And yes I need trigger for every checkbox click